# Breadcrumb and flyout on custom master page

Tags: 2013, navigation, master-page, html, breadcrumb

I have a master page that I wrote from scratch and applied through the Design Manager to one of my site collections. I would like to add the 2010-style breadcrumb and/or navigate-up flyout button in to this page, but the `ms-breadcrumb` term does not exist (nor does anything similar) and when I add the snippet for the breadcrumb it only displays site structure and not library/folder like the 2010 version did. (Both methods are referenced [here](http://blog.amtopm.be/2013/01/04/sp2013-adding-breadcrumbs/))

Is there a solution to one or both of these behaviors? Do I need to add more than just the snippet since I am using a 100% custom master page?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the reference term has changed in 2013.

You can add the breadcrumbs in 2013 by adding the following snippet to your master page:

```
<!--MS:<asp:sitemappath runat="server" sitemapproviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider" rendercurrentnodeaslink="false" hideinteriorrootnodes="true">-->
<!--ME:</asp:sitemappath>-->
```

Source http://blog.amtopm.be/2013/01/04/sp2013-adding-breadcrumbs/

Comment: Please, do not only provide links as answer. Copy the essence if the post here, and make sure to link to the source as well :)

Comment: Sorry, I was just looking for the same thing, came across this question and then found the answer myself so thought id help out.

Comment: No problem, it is not easy to know. The reason behind it is that the link can go bad, so if we have the essence here, is will still be useful!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this in a few different ways.  First, you can unhide the control in the master page itself, see my blog post about that: http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2013-restore-breadcrumb-navigate-up-navigation/.  Basically you find this code in the master page and remove the display:none style from the parent and visible=false attribute on the control:

```
<div class="ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox" style="display:none;">
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaBreadcrumbDropdown" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:PopoutMenu
        Visible="false"
        runat="server"
```

Also mentioned in that blog post is how to restore the breadcrumb control with backend code.  I have also packaged up that solution here: http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2013-restore-breadcrumb-navigate-up-navigation-part-2/.  You can just deploy the solution to your farm, activate the feature, and voila, your breadcrumb is there.